# Ignore small difference between numbers in Beyond Compare

Tags: beyondcompare3

I have 2 files with some number values in it and I want to compare them using Beyond Compare. But if the difference between two numbers is small enough, I want Beyond Compare to ignore those differences.

For example, I have the file named `file1.txt` with the values:

```
value1: 10
value2: 8.2
value3: 5.7
```

and the second file named `file2.txt` with the values:

```
value1: 8
value2: 8.4
value3: 6.3
```

I want Beyond Compare to show me differences only where the difference between two numbers is greater than 0.5, in this case, on line 1 and line 3.

Can someone tell me how could I do that? I tried with regular expressions but I didn't succeed.

**EDIT:**

I tried the answer @Chris Kennedy told, and this is the outcome:

[image: printscreen]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beyond Compare's Text Compare doesn't support ignoring differences with a numeric tolerance. It can only ignore differences based on text matching using regular expressions or text delimiters.

Beyond Compare 3's Data Compare (Table Compare in BC4) does support numeric tolerances. Load files the Data Compare, then click on the Rules toolbar button (referee icon). Go to the Columns tab. Double click on a column to edit it. Uncheck "Use default". Set the Type dropdown to Numeric. Enter a numeric tolerance. Note that Numeric Tolerance isn't available if Key is checked in the column settings.

Comment: I tried your answer, I found and follow all of the steps, but it seems like it doesn't work. I will update the question with a screenshot.

Comment: Actually, after I click on the Rules toolbar button, if I click on Edit Default(on the Columns tab) instead of double click on a column and follow the rest of the steps, it works :) Thanks a lot @Chris Edit your answer, so I could accept it.

Comment: My instructions are correct. In your screenshot, the numeric values are in column 2, but you edited settings for column 1, that is why it didn't work. If you edit the default column settings, it affects all columns that haven't been customized, which is why it worked. If you edited column 2 that would have worked without affecting the default for all column settings.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I misunderstood your steps in the first time :) Thanks